# Decoding Ebcdic

Tags: python, character-encoding, ebcdic

I'm being passed data that is ebcdic encoded.  Something like:

```
s = u'@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@ÂÖÉâÅ@ÉÄ'
```

Attempting to `.decode('cp500')` is wrong, but what's the correct approach?  If I copy the string into something like Notepad++ I can convert it from EBCDIC to ascii, but I can't seem to find a viable approach in python to achieve the same.  For what it's worth, the correct result is: `BOISE ID` (plus or minus space padding).

The information is being retrieved from a file of lines of JSON objects.  That file looks like this:

```
{ "command": "flush-text", "text": "@@@@@O@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@O" }
{ "command": "flush-text", "text": "@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@\u00C9\u00C4@\u00D5\u00A4\u0094\u0082\u0085\u0099z@@@@@@@@@@\u00D9\u00F5\u00F9\u00F7\u00F6\u00F8\u00F7\u00F2\u00F4" }
{ "command": "flush-text", "text": "@@@@@OmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmO" }
{ "command": "flush-text", "text": "@@@@@O@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@O" }
```

And the processing loop looks something like:

```
with open('myfile.txt', 'rb') as fh:
  for line in fh:
    data = json.loads(line)
```

Comment: Encode or decode? Why would you decode a Unicode string? Wouldn't you want to decode a byte string?

Comment: Agreed.  But ... what I'm getting is already in a unicode string - it came from `json.loads`.  It's kind of a cluster, tbh.  But I'm struggling with how to get from what I have to work with to what I need.

Comment: It sounds like you aren't really clear what you have to work with.

Comment: Are you using Python 2 or 3?

Comment: Can you add a snipplet on how you get hold of this data in your python script? When it comes from a file, them maybe you should open in the right encoding....

Comment: @cdarke - 2.  I'd considered trying to use 3, but I'm not sure the libraries I'm using are all compatible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If Notepad++ converts it ok, then you should simply need:

**Python 2.7:**

```
with io.open('myfile.txt', 'r', encoding="cp500") as fh:
  for line in fh:
    data = json.loads(line)
```

**Python 3.x:**

```
with open('myfile.txt', 'r', encoding="cp500") as fh:
  for line in fh:
    data = json.loads(line)
```

This uses a TextWrapper to decode the file as it's read using the given decoding. `io` module provides Python 3 `open` to Python 2.x, with codecs/TextWrapper and universal newline support

Answer (score 3):

My guess is that you need the value of the corresponding Unicode ordinals as bytes, and then decode that with cp500.

```
>>> s = u'@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@ÂÖÉâÅ@ÉÄ'
>>> bytearray(ord(c) for c in s).decode('cp500')
u'                   BOISE ID'
```

Alternatively:

```
>>> s.encode('latin-1').decode('cp500')
u'                   BOISE ID'
```

Comment: This answer works correctly, but I'm interested in testing the `io` module further so I went with that approach.

Comment: @g.d.d.c the other answer is the correct approach. I assumed you got your unicode string from *somewhere* and had to deal with what you got.