# How can I open .ebc (ebcdic) file on my laptop via python?

Tags: python, database, file, utf-8, decoding

[UPD I have opened file and found this format. How I can decode 00000000....](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nebzD.png)

I need to open .ebc file on Python. The size of this file is approximately 12GB.

I have used a huge amount of tools and Python libraries for this action, but it is obvious that I am doing something in a wrong way. I can't find suitable encoding.

I tried to read the file line by line because of it size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python [lists](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings) two code pages for EBCDIC, "cp424" (Hebrew) and "cp500" (Western scripts).

Use it like this:

```
with open(path, encoding='cp500') as f:
    for line in f:
        # process one line of text
```

Note: if the file is 12G in size, you'll want to avoid to call `f.read()` or `f.readlines()`, as both would read the entire file into memory.
On a laptop, this is likely to freeze your system.
Instead, iterate over the contents line by line using Python's default line iteration.

If you just want to re-encode the file with a modern encoding, eg. the very popular UTF-8, use the following pattern:

```
with open(in_path, encoding='cp500') as src, open(out_path, 'w', encoding='utf8') as dest:
    dest.writelines(src)
```

This should re-encode the file with a low-memory footprint, as it reads, converts and writes the contents line by line.

Comment: It looks like 'cp037' and 'cp273' are also based on EBCDIC, even though the linked table doesn't mention this. You might have to do a bit of trial and error if the source of your file doesn't tell you what codepage exactly was used to encode it.

Comment: I have opened file and found a lot of 00000000000 (picture in my question). The share of understandable information is extremely small. Maybe I can make another decode operation? @lenz

Comment: It looks like the next step is parsing the format. From what I can tell from the picture, the runs of 0s are actually repeated occurrences of the digit "0", not null bytes or something like this, so no additional decoding step is appropriate here. But it looks like you didn't yet find the correct codec; you still have some boxes and odd-looking "æ" characters.

Comment: Is there really no documentation on the file format?

Comment: About the "æ" characters: it's quite probable that there isn't an existing codec that correctly interprets this. At the time EBCDIC was in use, it's possible people just remapped the character ad-hoc: "We don't need 'æ', let's use this codepoint for some other character which is missing from the character set." If there's no documentation, you'll have to guess what should actually be there and do some `str.replace()` operation.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have any documentation on the file format. I know that this file include oil&gas information about reservoirs.

Comment: Bad luck. It looks like you need to reverse-engineer the format... To me, it looks like it could be a table with fixed field widths, but from the image I can't tell if these  are tabs or spaces, so this is really just a wild guess.

Comment: I have found this IBM document: https://www.ibm.com/downloads/cas/G01BQVRV @lenz

Comment: Moreover, cp500 is ok: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35111900/decoding-ebcdic

It is strange